# Is it possible to download images from a private telegram channel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Is it possible to download images from a private telegram channel without admin rights using Python?
Basically what I want is the script to wait till a picture is sent in the private channel and if one got sent, I want it download the picture with the filename increasing(img1, img2...). Problem is I dont have admin rights in this channel and no Bot.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible without Python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I dont

Comment: I'm curious if you were able to do it @jonathangilbert

Answer (score 0):

Sure. If you have access to this channel, you can use the "telethon" library to implement this function.
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/

The first thing you have to do is get a channel

```
input_entity = await UserMethods.get_input_entity(client, peer="https://t.me/example")
entity = await client.get_entity(input_entity)
```

and then:

```
client.download_profile_photo(entity, file=photo_path)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).